# Converting different string formats of date to specific DateTime format

Tags: c#, date

I have different string formats of date in my files in c#, like;

- 2018-07-02T19:04:11.188-04:00
- 06/15/2018 //mm/dd/yyyy
- 22/06/2018 //dd/mm/yyyy
- 04/06/2018 //mm/dd/yyyy

I am trying to convert like this,

```
string publishDate= "2018-07-02T19:04:11.188-04:00";
//string publishDate= "06/15/2018";
//string publishDate= "22/06/2018";

DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(publishDate);
return date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

for `06/15/2018` it says `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` however, it converts `22/06/2018` perfectly to 22-Jun-2018.

and how would it determine if date `04/06/2018` refers to `mm/dd/yyyy`

Comment: By you telling it in what format the dates are. It has some default formats but if you have random strings you’ll have to tell it what they mean.

Comment: Is your question actually "how would it determine if `04/06/2018` refers to `MM/dd/yyyy` or `dd/MM/yyyy`"? (The answer is you can't unless it is in context of other similar dates.)

Answer (score 1):

try this piece of code :)

```
DateTime date;

if (!DateTime.TryParse(publishDate, out date)){
    date = DateTime.ParseExact(publishDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```